# How to integrate float-label into a php form

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am trying to implement this [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/iamjordanlittle/pen/AHdfn)  into my PHP form where all fields come from a database.

Php Code:

```
    <?php if ($type == 'recaptcha') { ?>
<label class="control-label col-md-2"></label>
<?php } else { ?>
<label class="control-label col-md-2 <?php if (!empty($error)) { ?>has-error<?php } ?>" for="<?php echo $element_id ?>"><?php echo $title ?></label>
<?php } ?>
<div class="input-group col-md-9 <?php if (!empty($error)) { ?>has-error<?php } ?>">
    <?php echo $item_html ?>
</div>  
<span class="help-block">
    <div class="element_description"><?php echo $description ?></div>
    <?php if ($error) { ?>
    <div class="element_error has-error"><?php echo $error ?></div>
    <?php } ?>
</span>
```

Now it shows like this:
[image]

I have tried a few things but everything comes from

```
<?php echo $item_html ?>
```

So I can't really seperate the dynamic labels.
Can anyone guide me how to achieve this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with php. Try setting the thing up without php first, and then add your php code to the html form?

Comment: Doesn't `<?php this($kind); ?>` of `<?php $code; ?>` make `<?php your($eyes).bleed(); ?>`?

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments but the code without php is there in codepen and I have to integrate it with the php form and I figured that $item_html populates the page with all the fields

Comment: @Chris PHP ain't no python, its `your($eyes)->bleed()` ;)

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand what the question is here.  Should the provided code be in a loop? What is the desired output of your code? What is the actual output? What specifically isn't what you want it to be?

Comment: @PatrickQ The image shown is the current output and the codepen example id the desired output

Comment: The codepen includes CSS and Javascript.  You're showing neither of those here.  Are you including those?  I'm inclined to agree with Hallur that this really isn't a PHP issue.

Comment: @PatrickQ Yes I know this isn't php issue And I am applying those css and JS which is fine the problem here is $inner_html creates the input tag and I am not trying to add label to it